# Cucumber tests not reading cucumber.properties file

Tags: java, testing, junit, cucumber, junit5

I created a small snippet Spring Boot application using Junit5 and Cucumber.
Because I need to use Junit5 I am using `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` which does not support the annotation `CucumberOptions`

As quoted in cucumber.io website:

> When property parsing functionality is not provided by the runner (i.e. cucumber-junit-platform-engine) Cucumber will in order of precedence parse properties from system properties, environment variables and the cucumber.properties file.

Because of this I added the following a file named `cucumber.properties` to my directory `src/test/resources` with the following content:

```
cucumber.plugin=json:target/cucumber-reports/,pretty
```

Yet, when I run my tests this file seems to be ignored as no reports are generated while if I pass the same property through cli arguments such as:

`mvn test -Dcucumber.plugin=json:target/cucumber-reports/,pretty` it generates the expected json reports.

I have also tried putting the file under `src/main/resources` and under `src/main/test/cucumber.demo` (where the feature files are located), but none of these attempts worked. Any idea why the file is being ignored?

Here is my Runner class:

```java
@Cucumber
public class CucumberTest {
    
}
```

and my Step Definition class:

```java
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class StepDefinition {

    @Autowired
    String bean;

    //Step Definition 
    (...)

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using Cucumber with JUnit5 through the `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` the tests are run by the JUnit platform. The JUnit Platform provides property parsing functionality.

There are several different ways to provide properties to the JUnit Platform. One of them being the `junit-platform.properties` file. You can read about it in more detail here:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#configuration-options
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params

Comment: If you are running IntelliJ, the `junit-platform.properties` may not be taken into account depending on how you run the tests, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227508/Support-cucumber-junit-platform-engine